# Arquivo .class não é gerado

Tags: java

Já testei, através do prompt de comando, e o java e javac estão instalados.
O problema é que o arquivo `.class` não é criado.

Digitando o diretório eu consigo achar a pasta, mas não o arquivo que eu quero dentro da pasta (aparece uma mensagem de erro).

Comment: Configurou as variáveis de ambiente?

Comment: Você deve [edit] a pergunta e colocar mais informações, como o erro que apareceu.

Comment: Você compilou o arquivo .java? Exemplo: `javac SuaClasse.java`. Os arquivos .class são gerados a partir da compilação do arquivo .java

Comment: Se esta iniciando em Java, recomento este material: http://www.loiane.com/2013/02/instalando-e-configurando-o-java-no-windows-8/ e também as video aulas da própria autora postado no final do artigo.

Comment: A pergunta deve sempre conter o erro, então qual a mensagem de erro?

Answer (score 2):

Sua pergunta não está clara mas vou tentar responder mesmo assim.

Primeiro crie um arquivo `HelloWorld.java`:

```java
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

E coloque este arquivo na pasta aonde você quer compilar. Vamos supor que esta pasta seja `C:\projetos\helloworld`.

Então, no prompt de comando, estando na pasta `C:\projetos\helloworld`, você digita o seguinte comando:

```
javac HelloWorld.java
```

E então o arquivo `HelloWorld.class` deverá ter surgido na pasta. Agora você digita o seguinte comando:

```
java HelloWorld
```

E então `Hello World` deverá ser imprimido no console.

Se isto não funcionar, informe o que aconteceu de inesperado e qual foi a mensagem de erro, caso apareça alguma. Se der certo, tente fazer o mesmo com o programa que você quer compilar.